# How to create/update/load a HTML file at runtime

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview

I need to create and open an HTML file at runtime.

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <form name="Home" method="POST" action='' >
          <input id='Title' type='hidden' value="Mr" name='Title'/>
          <input id='Name' type='hidden' value="bala" name='Name'/>
           .
           .
           .
         </form>
         <script language='javascript'>
            //java script
         </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

In above format, i need to update `value` field at runtime. After updating I want to open this html file within my android application.

**Update:**
I know we can crate HTML file like below..

```
public static String createHTML(Study study) {
    String format =
            "<html>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<form name="Home" method="POST" action='' >" +
            "<input id='Title' type='hidden' value='%d' name='Title'/>" +
            .
            .
            .
            .
            "   </body>" +
            "</html>";
    return String.format(format, study.title, study.name...);
}
```

but i wank to know is there any other way to create HTML file like creating XML file using [XmlSerializer](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/android-xml-adventure-create-write-xml-data/)
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot 'run' an HTML file.

Comment: Question updated
@Rajesh
ok..how to update/open within my app.. using webview ??

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) documentation.

Comment: @Rajesh How to create html file. i need to create a file in above format(50 to 60 lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create html file.

1. Open file
2. Write text characters comprising the HTML
3. Close file

If you need more details, the Oracle Java Tutorial has lessons on basic Java constructs, and on how to do simple file I/O.

---

There are other more "elegant" ways of doing this kind of thing in different contexts (e.g. in a web service) but if this the sum total of what you need to do, then ... keep it simple.

---

> ... is there any other way to create HTML file like creating XML file using XmlSerializer.

Not HTML.  You could create XHTML that way through.

Having said that, constructing HTML or XHTML that way sounds like a poor idea.  The resulting code would be neither readable or efficient ... compared with string concatenation or template-based approaches.

(Try it and see ...)

Comment: is there anyway to create html file like an xml file using **XmlSerializer**

`XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = Xml. newSerializer ();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 
    xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
    // start DOCUMENT
    xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
    // open tag: <record>
    xmlSerializer.startTag("", Study.RECORD);
    // open tag: <study>
    xmlSerializer.startTag("", Study.STUDY);
    xmlSerializer.attribute("", Study.ID, String.valueOf(study.mId));`

Comment: hi Stephen..as your advice finally I ended with [this](http://pastie.org/8270087#18-27,30,33) solutions. is it good approach?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run html file runtime then try using this code.

```
 webview_data.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlString,"text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

And make sure if you want to use any css or javascript file then put it into android assest folder..

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed better ways of generating HTML pages in Android than manual string concatenation. There are a few slick Java libraries that will do it for you (recall that you can use regular Java libraries within your Android project pretty easily).

- RenderSnake: http://rendersnake.org/index.html
- FreeMarker Java: http://freemarker.org/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create MyHtml file

   MyHtml.html

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
       <form name="Home" method="POST" action='' >
       <input id='Name' type='hidden' value="MyName" name='Name'/>
       <input id='FirstName' type='hidden' value="MyFName" name='FirstName'/>          
          .
          .
          .
        </form>
        <script language='javascript'>
           //java script
        </script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. stored in Assets folder as MyHtml.html
3. Read and update this file in my app like below

   ```
   InputStream is = getAssets().open("MyHtml.html");
       int size = is.available();

       byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
       is.read(buffer);
       is.close();

       String str = new String(buffer);
       str = str.replace("MyName", "James Bala");
       str = str.replace("MyFName", "James");
       .
       .
       .
   ```
4. then i loaded my html file in webView like below

   ```
   myWebView.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
   ```

As Stephen's advice finally I ended with this solutions. Thanks @Stephen