# Webview is not displaying Gujarati font

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fonts

I am not able to display **Gujarati Font** in **WebView** for Xolo, Sony Xperia, Nexus Tab device.
Can anyone help me for this issue?

Comment: In html String that is return from web.  I have set like this <meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8><style>@font-face{font-family:'myface';src:url('file:///android_asset/fonts/SHRUTI.TTF')}body{font-family:'myface'}</style>

Comment: How to load `HTML` page into `Webview`? post u r code

Comment: webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");

Comment: It's perfectly working in my `Nexus 4` and `Samsung Note2` but it's not working into `Micromax A89S`. So, here i think all the devices Customized `Android Platform Classes` as per their Requirement. Like Sony always `Customized Android java classes`. or there are nice SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900658/how-to-change-font-face-of-webview-in-android/7395170#7395170) try this one

Comment: Use `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, mimeType, encoding, null);`. Refer this [load-a-html-file-at-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416182/how-to-create-update-load-a-html-file-at-runtime/18417164#18417164)

Comment: You got any solution for the same

Comment: you have to add the font in to use asset folder and load the font from their

Comment: @CodingISLife Can u give any Example?

Comment: @Palak Got Any Solution for that?

Comment: hello you found any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put all html page into a asset folder and sdcard and any webserver. Load the url simply:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```

like that. In my case, all web pages are store on web server and we are choice of button to display a web page for different language.